# Servlet "newspring" is not available

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, dispatcher

Trying to set up a new spring project and im having this issue where I get this error (HTTP Status 404 - Servlet newspring is not available) when I navigate to a page that I expect to get routed through to a controller.

web.xml

```
<servlet> 
 <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class> 
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet> 

<servlet-mapping> 
 <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name> 
 <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping>
```

So I looked in the tomcat logs and I see this exception:

> SEVERE: Error loading
>   WebappClassLoader   delegate: false
>   repositories:
>       /WEB-INF/classes/
>   ----------> Parent Classloader: org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@a1807c
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
>           at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1387)
>           at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1233)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1095)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:993)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4149)

but the supposedly missing class is actually present in the spring-webmvc.jar which is present in the WEB-INF/libs(at tomcatfolder/webapp/newSpring/WEB-INF/libs).

Is it unable to look here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I read correctly, the folder should be `/WEB-INF/lib`, not `/WEB-INF/libs` - note the lack of s at the end!